# How can I add item to requisition list even if it is not in stock?

Tags: magento2, b2b

I would like a user to be able to add items to the requisition list that are not in stock. In the b2b module there is a validatio.php vile with this code-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\RequisitionList\Model\RequisitionListItem;

use Magento\RequisitionList\Api\Data\RequisitionListItemInterface;

/**
 * Requisition List Item validation service.
*
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.0
* /
class Validation
{
/**
 * @var ValidatorInterface[]
 */
private $validators;

/**
 * @param ValidatorInterface[] $validators [optional]
 */
public function __construct(
    $validators = []
) {
    $this->validators = $validators;
}

/**
 * Validate list item.
 *
 * @param RequisitionListItemInterface $item
 * @return array
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function validate(RequisitionListItemInterface $item)
{
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($this->validators as $validator) {
        $errors = array_merge($errors, $validator->validate($item));
        if (count($errors)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}

/**
 * Is list item valid.
 *
 * @param RequisitionListItemInterface $item
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isValid(RequisitionListItemInterface $item)
{
    return !count($this->validate($item));
 }
 }
```

Is there any easy way to stop that validation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create plugin for this.

**app/code/SR/StackExchange/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\RequisitionList\Model\RequisitionListItem\Validation">
        <plugin name="remove_requisition_list_item_validation"
                type="SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Model\RequisitionListItem\Validation" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/SR/StackExchange/Plugin/Model/RequisitionListItem/Validation.php**

```
<?php
namespace SR\StackExchange\Plugin\Model\RequisitionListItem;

use Magento\RequisitionList\Api\Data\RequisitionListItemInterface;

class Validation
{
    public function aroundValidate(
        \Magento\RequisitionList\Model\RequisitionListItem\Validation $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        RequisitionListItemInterface $item
    ) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I can now add the quantity of 1 item onto my requisition list even if it is out of stock. But if I try to add 2 I get that error again. Any ideas?